# "Flatten" multidimension array by "combining" children (i.e: 7 x 7 = 49)

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have looked up a lot threads similar to this, but the main difference is that in those threads the "children" elements only had 1 value each. My problem is slightly different:

You have a 2-level array, where the first level is "option type" (i.e: Color, Size, Fabric, etc) and the second level is the "option value" (i.e: Red, Blue, Size 6, Size 7, Leather, Cotton, etc). I would like the "flatten" this array into a single level array that combines the options (i.e: Red - Size 6 - Leather, Red - Size 6 - Cotton, Blue - Size 6 - Leather, etc).

So if there are 2 option types with 7 options each, the resulting array would have 49 keys, if there are 3 option types with 5 options each, the resulting array would have 125 keys.

**Example Data Set (2 Option Types with 2 options each)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 1
            [option_name] => Color
            [option_values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [poa_id] => 24
                            [poa_name] => Black
                            [poa] => POA575628
                            [poa_price] => 0.0000
                            [small_image] => http://img2.banggood.com/thumb/other_items//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_3.jpg
                            [view_image] => http://img3.banggood.com/thumb/view//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_3.jpg
                            [large_image] => http://img3.banggood.com/thumb/large//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_3.jpg
                            [list_grid_image] => http://img1.banggood.com/thumb/list_grid//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_3.jpg
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [poa_id] => 41
                            [poa_name] => Brown
                            [poa] => POA575649
                            [poa_price] => 0.0000
                            [small_image] => http://img1.banggood.com/thumb/other_items//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_5.jpg
                            [view_image] => http://img2.banggood.com/thumb/view//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_5.jpg
                            [large_image] => http://img1.banggood.com/thumb/large//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_5.jpg
                            [list_grid_image] => http://img.banggood.com/thumb/list_grid//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_5.jpg
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 8
            [option_name] => Size(US)
            [option_values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [poa_id] => 10384
                            [poa_name] => 6.5
                            [poa] => POA575643
                            [poa_price] => 0.0000
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [poa_id] => 90
                            [poa_name] => 7
                            [poa] => POA575644
                            [poa_price] => 0.0000
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

**Required Data Set (2 X 2 = 4 array keys)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (   
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [poa_id] => 24
                    [poa_name] => Black
                    [poa] => POA575628
                    [poa_price] => 0.0000
                    [small_image] => http://img2.banggood.com/thumb/other_items//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_3.jpg
                    [view_image] => http://img3.banggood.com/thumb/view//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_3.jpg
                    [large_image] => http://img3.banggood.com/thumb/large//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_3.jpg
                    [list_grid_image] => http://img1.banggood.com/thumb/list_grid//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_3.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [poa_id] => 10384
                    [poa_name] => 6.5
                    [poa] => POA575643
                    [poa_price] => 0.0000
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (   
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [poa_id] => 24
                    [poa_name] => Black
                    [poa] => POA575628
                    [poa_price] => 0.0000
                    [small_image] => http://img2.banggood.com/thumb/other_items//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_3.jpg
                    [view_image] => http://img3.banggood.com/thumb/view//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_3.jpg
                    [large_image] => http://img3.banggood.com/thumb/large//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_3.jpg
                    [list_grid_image] => http://img1.banggood.com/thumb/list_grid//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_3.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [poa_id] => 90
                    [poa_name] => 7
                    [poa] => POA575644
                    [poa_price] => 0.0000
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (   
             [0] => Array
                (
                    [poa_id] => 41
                    [poa_name] => Brown
                    [poa] => POA575649
                    [poa_price] => 0.0000
                    [small_image] => http://img1.banggood.com/thumb/other_items//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_5.jpg
                    [view_image] => http://img2.banggood.com/thumb/view//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_5.jpg
                    [large_image] => http://img1.banggood.com/thumb/large//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_5.jpg
                    [list_grid_image] => http://img.banggood.com/thumb/list_grid//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_5.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [poa_id] => 10384
                    [poa_name] => 6.5
                    [poa] => POA575643
                    [poa_price] => 0.0000
                )
        )

    [3] => Array
        (   
             [0] => Array
                (
                    [poa_id] => 41
                    [poa_name] => Brown
                    [poa] => POA575649
                    [poa_price] => 0.0000
                    [small_image] => http://img1.banggood.com/thumb/other_items//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_5.jpg
                    [view_image] => http://img2.banggood.com/thumb/view//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_5.jpg
                    [large_image] => http://img1.banggood.com/thumb/large//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_5.jpg
                    [list_grid_image] => http://img.banggood.com/thumb/list_grid//upload/2015/09/SKU279024_5.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [poa_id] => 90
                    [poa_name] => 7
                    [poa] => POA575644
                    [poa_price] => 0.0000
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: @Bobot I have tried implementing this as a recursive function where I separate the first "option type set" using array_shift() and then call the function with the remaining option sets until there are none left, and then combining the separated option set with the returned "children sets". However, I have been unable to find a solution where all the option set values are on the same "level", there is always some additional unwanted children arrays (due to recursion). I have been unable to come up with the correct algorithm to accomplish what I need.

Comment: @Bobot My reasoning currently is to create an array with the first set of options, then in the second recursion "duplicate" what is there for each 2nd option and add the second option, and repeat for all option sets and then remove any keys where count($array[$key]) < count($optionSets), but I think this is a very inefficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
function populateOptions($options,$populatedArray)
{
    $optionSet = array_shift($options);
    $returnArray = array();
    foreach($optionSet['option_values'] as $option)
    {
        foreach($populatedArray as $addedOption) 
        {
            $addedOption[] = $option;
            $returnArray[] = $addedOption;
        }
    }

    if (!empty(count($options))) $returnArray = populateOptions($options, $returnArray);

    return $returnArray;    
}

$productOptions = populateOptions($optionSets,array('0' => null));
```